# How to detect the CAlayer that is been touched if it is in movement with an animation

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, touchesmoved

I want to detect which of my CALayer is been touched with a swype. Those CALayers are moving through a CGPath and they are also rotating.
I tried with touchesMoved in my view controller checking which of the CALayers contains the point with:

```
    for (UITouch* t in touches) {
        CGPoint point=[t locationInView:self.view];
        for (int i=0; i<[layers count]; i++) {
            if ([[layers objectAtIndex:i] containsPoint:[myLayer convertPoint:point toLayer:[layers objectAtIndex:i]]]){
                doSomething
                }

            }

        }
```

It didn´t work. It seems like if the CALayer was always in the position before the animation.

I tried also to subclass UIImageView with touchesMoved and then animate the CALayer of those UIImageView. And the same happen to me. I have animated the CALayer because I don't know how to animate an UIImageView to follow a CGPath.

What can I do?

Thank You very much.

Comment: I found the solution. When the CALayer is been animated, I have to to ask containsPoint or hitTest to [theLayer presentationLayer] instead of itself.

I found it here:

how find position of CAlayer during animation?.